# Create ZIP via PHP in a specific directory

Tags: php

I found this awesome code to create a ZIP file using PHP via this link [compress/archive folder using php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828385/compress-archive-folder-using-php-script)

```
<?php
// Config Vars 

$sourcefolder = "./"           ; // Default: "./" 
$zipfilename  = "myarchive.zip"; // Default: "myarchive.zip"
$timeout      = 5000           ; // Default: 5000

// instantate an iterator (before creating the zip archive, just
// in case the zip file is created inside the source folder)
// and traverse the directory to get the file list.
$dirlist = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sourcefolder);
$filelist = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirlist);

// set script timeout value 
ini_set('max_execution_time', $timeout);

// instantate object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// create and open the archive 
if ($zip->open("$zipfilename", ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive");
}

// add each file in the file list to the archive
foreach ($filelist as $key=>$value) {
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}

// close the archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive ". $zipfilename . " created successfully.";

// And provide download link ?>
<a href="http:<?php echo $zipfilename;?>" target="_blank">
Download <?php echo $zipfilename?></a>
```

I would like to create the zip in a particular directory.

Comment: Have you tried using a complete path for the zip file name, instead of just a file name?

Comment: "I found this awesome code" - have you actually tried to understand how it works or do just want us to adjust it for you before you paste it into your app?

Comment: But dude it's awesome

Comment: Please take the reference of this code. It will resolve your issue.
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('testPDFZip.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob(APPLICATION_PATH."pages/recruitment/uploads/test_pdf_folder/*") as $file) {
 echo "<br />iteration";
 $new_filename = end(explode("/",$file));
    $zip->addFile($file,"emp/".$new_filename);
}
   
$zip->close();

Answer (score 3):

```
$zipfilename  = "/path/to/my/zip/folder/myarchive.zip";
```

Simply make sure the folder is [writable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

Comment: It doesn't work because the download link will display incorrect and will divert me to a page not found or my website rather than downlaod the link.

Comment: Well, certainly you need to add the path to the download link :)

Comment: The folder is writable for sure cos it worked plenty of times

Comment: Is this a PEBCAK issue perhaps?

Comment: Sorry but I am still brand new to PHP.