# PHP FILES Recursive backup of directories, deleting main directory

Tags: php, file, recursion, directory

**Function:**

```
function scandir_recursive($dir) {
    $items = scandir($dir);

    foreach($items as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        $file = $dir . '/' . $item;
        echo "$file<br />";

        if (is_dir($file)) {
            scandir_recursive($file);
        }
    }
}
scandir_recursive($path);
```

**Output:**

```
EEAOC/EN/1001/data
EEAOC/EN/1001/data/New Text Document.txt
EEAOC/EN/1001/data/troll.txt
EEAOC/EN/1002/data
EEAOC/EN/1002/data/New Text Document.txt
EEAOC/EN/1002/data/troll.txt
EEAOC/EN/1003/data
EEAOC/EN/1003/data/New Text Document.txt
EEAOC/EN/1003/data/troll.txt
EEAOC/EN/1004/data
EEAOC/EN/1004/data/New Text Document.txt
EEAOC/EN/1004/data/troll.txt
```

Is it possible to delete those empty directories and keep files?
such deleting `EEAOC/EN/1001/data &EEAOC/EN/1002/data& EEAOC/EN/1003/data &EEAOC/EN/1004/data`

I want to keep remaining how?

Comment: please let me know if I could answer your question. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As shown from your function-output, the directories are not empty.

I suppose that the data is of low value and just needs to be backed up. I assume you are running Linux from your choice of a slash rather than a backslash.  Naturally directories incur links or inodes, with metadata, which in linux can be checked via

```
df -hi
```

The Inode-Ids of files can be shown via the -i flag of `ls`

```
ls -i filename
ls -iltr
ls -ltri `echo $HOME`
```

Inodes take up space, and introduce overhead in file-system operations. So much to the motivation to remove the directories.

PHP's `rmdir` function to remove directories requires that `The directory must be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this`. It is also non-recursive.

- **Approach 1**: flatten filenames and move the files to a backup directory, then remove the empty directories
- **Approach 2**: incrementally archive and remove the directories

**#Approach 1**
Your choice should depend on how easy and frequent your file access occurs.

function scandir_recursive($dir) {
    $items = scandir($dir);

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    $file = $dir . '/' . $item;
    $fnameflat = $dir . '_' . $item;
    echo "$file<br />\n";
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        scandir_recursive($file);
    }
    if(is_file($file)){
        rename($file, '~/backup/'.$fnameflat);
    }
}
```

}
    scandir_recursive($path);

Afterwards use [this function by SeniorDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php), to unlink files and directories, or run

```
`exec("rmdir -rf $path")`
```

This is not recommended.

**#Approach 2**

Archive the directory using `exec("tar -cvzf backup".date().".tar.gz $path");` or [using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828385/compress-archive-folder-using-php-script).

Then remove the directory aferwards, as described in #1.